# Laravel 5 Passing Form $request as Array in Controller

Tags: php, forms, controller, laravel-5

When processing a request from a form it is I pass the $request parameters to a email template:

```
public function store(CreateFormRequest $request)
{
    Mail::send('emails.contact',
        array(
            'firstname'  => $request->get('firstname'),
            'familyname' => $request->get('familyname'),
            'email'      => $request->get('email')
        ), function ($message)
        {
            $message->from('noreply@senderdomain.com');
            $message->to('subscriber@subscriberdomain.com', 'Subscriber name')->subject('Thank you for subscribing');
        });
}
```

Is it possible to pass the $request parameters at once as Array?

**Like this:**

```
    Mail::send('emails.contact',
        $request->toArray(), function ($message)
        {
            $message->from('noreply@senderdomain.com');
            $message->to('subscriber@subscriberdomain.com', 'Subscriber name')->subject('Thank you for subscribing');
        });
```

**toArray()** is of course not working but is there a way to do this? Or is this a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases your best bet is the `only()` method. It let's you quickly specify all values *that you want* ignoring everything else.

```
$data = $request->only('firstname', 'familyname', 'email');
Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function ($message)
{
    $message->from('noreply@senderdomain.com');
    $message->to('subscriber@subscriberdomain.com', 'Subscriber name')->subject('Thank you for subscribing');
});
```

Comment: or `$request->except()` if you have a lot of fields and most of them you need

Comment: @mcklayin Just be careful as `except()` let's everything through and request parameters can be easily manipulated...